# How can I INSERT new values and values from an already existing table?

Tags: javascript, mysql, sql, node.js

I'm currently learning MySQL and have learned the INSERTO INTO statement and the INSERT INTO SELECT statement.

The INSERT INTO statement works like this:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

While the INSERT INTO SELECT works like this:

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
WHERE condition;
```

What I'm trying to do is add new values while also adding values that I already have stored in another table.

```
con.query("INSERT INTO vehicles (vehicleType, vehicleModel, vehicleOwner, vehicleSpawnX, vehicleSpawnY, vehicleSpawnZ)")
```

From the query above, I already have the vehicleOwner value stored in another table, while the other ones I've just gotten.
How can I do this? Add a VALUES statement before SELECT?
I'm using SQL Workbench 8.0 and JavaScript. Also, all the values are NOT NULL, so I can't make two different queries, unless on the first one I add temporary values that I'll update on the second one.

What I want to replace:

- vehicleType -> "players"
- vehicleModel -> vehicleCreate.model
- vehicleOwner -> playerID FROM players table
- vehicleSpawnX -> pos.x
- vehicleSpawnY -> pos.y
- vehicleSpawnZ -> pos.z

Thanks!

Comment: You can use `SELECT vehicleOwner, 'car' AS vehicleType FROM otherTable` and so on - if you specify the column names in the `INSERT` you can also do away with the `AS vehicleType` and rely on the position of the column in the select result.

Comment: What is `pos` here? And is vehicleCreate.model static?

Comment: Try this type of SELECT standalone in an SQL client to see how it behaves: `SELECT 'hello'`, `SELECT 'hello' AS abc`, `SELECT 'hello' AS abc, 'world' AS xyz`, `SELECT realColumn1, realColumn2, realColumn3 AS newName, 'hello' AS abc, 'world' AS xyz FROM realTable` (the last example requires a table `realTable` with columns of at least `realColumn1`, `realColumn2` and `realColumn3`)

Comment: @aRvi it's the player position, an integer. I don't know if it's static

Comment: That's very confusing @CherryDT, but I'll try to do it

Comment: Think of it this way: it's just a SELECT whose output direct goes into an INSERT. You can SELECT anything - static values like `'hello'` as well as values from another table (or even multiple tables). So you can SELECT columns from a row of a table and just add additional columns that didn't exist in the table by providing their values in the SELECT column list manually (with AS they can even have a column name).

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible... But you can select data and store that on variables, then you will store it in another table

Comment: I think I'll do that. Thanks.

Comment: Actually it is possible, as I described.

Answer (score 0):

You would construct a query.  Your data model is a bit hard to follow since you give no examples of the data or of what you really want to do.

So let me give a simpler example.  Say, you have a table with two columns for two players and you want to put the ids into a table -- but using their names.  The query would look like:

```
insert into pairs (playerId1, playerId2)
    select p1.playerId, p2.playerId
    from players p1 join
         players p2
         on p1.name = ? and p2.name = ?;
```

The `?` are for parameter placeholders. I assume you know to *aways* use parameters when passing values into a query.